# How to "search file and send result into vim" in one command?

Tags: vim

I used:

```
find ~/web_project -name "config_*.php" -print | xargs vim
```

In vim, anything is ok. But, if exit vim, terminal is freeze.

My env: osx 10.6, macvim

Answer (score 4):

```
vim $(find ~/web_project -name "config_*.php")
```

frequently I want to check my find command first, so

```
find ~/web_project -name "config_*.php"
vim $(!!)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try (tested on 10.5) ..

```
$ vim `find ~/web_project -name "config_*.php"`
```

Comment: This can be simplified into `$ vim \`find ~/web_project -name "config_*.php"\``